# convert a javascript json-stringified string into a php array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, post

A javascript object (namely `contract_details`) is json-stringified to be sent via a jquery post resquest. Accordingly it is sent and received in the php file being called.

Javascript:

```
 contract_details= {};

contract_details['week_pay']=1;
    contract_details['daily_pay']=1;

$.post("add_contract_now.php",{

    contract_details:JSON.stringify(contract_details)

    },function(response){

        $(".result").html(response);

    }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="result"></div>
```

add_contract_now.php has :

```
$contract_details=$_POST['contract_details'];
```

How can I convert `$contract_details;` into an associative array  ?

Comment: Use `json_decode();` in PHP to read stringified JSON data.

Comment: wanted to accept your response as the answer. But how?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I know. But Tomazs did not make any answer, just commented

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: Ah, sorry, misread that. Yeah, you can't accept comments as answers. (Answers should be posted as answers, comments as comments.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, can you post it as an answer ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed: It **is** posted as an answer. (In fact, I posted it as one.) I can't post it as an answer on Tomasz's behalf, he should have made it an answer in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

You can decode JSON using [`json_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
$contract_details = json_decode($_POST['contract_details']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode):

```
$contract_details = $_POST['contract_details'];
$decoded = json_decode($contract_details);
print_r($decoded);
```

If you want the results as an associative array instead, you can use:

```
$decoded = json_decode($contract_details, TRUE);
```

Later, if you want to loop through the data, use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop, like so:

```
foreach ($decoded as $value) {

//do your thing

}
```

Hope this helps!